# Was Han in error about imperial warship designations?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

The massive, triangular Imperial starships that appear in the original *Star Wars* trilogy (Han calls them "the big Corellian ships") are well known to be "Star Destroyers."  Since these vessels are clearly not capable of destroying any stars, the name seems to indicate that they are spacegoing equivalents of naval destroyers.  As anyone who had played Battleship knows, destroyers (originally short for "torpedo boat destroyers") are the smallest class of heavy sea-going warships.

Cruisers are larger warships, although still smaller than battleships.  However, as the Millennium Falcon is escaping from Tatooine, Han Solo identifies the first ship he sees chasing them as an "imperial cruiser."  Is there an explanation in some secondary source of why he makes this apparent error?

Comment: Question contains a factual error; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124050/has-a-star-destroyer-ever-actually-destroyed-a-star/124068#124068

Comment: @Valorum That answer agrees with me.

Comment: It disagrees that Star Destroyers are the "smallest class of heavy warships".

Comment: @Valorun Which isn't what I said.  Destroyers are the heaviest type of real-world warships.

Comment: Why did you revert my edit? *Millennium Falcon* [should be italicized, as it is the name of a ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Naming_conventions_(ships)). *Star Wars* [follows this real-world convention](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon).

Comment: @Null - that's the wiki. The official StarWars.com site most certainly doesn't follow this convention; https://www.starwars.com/databank/millennium-falcon

Comment: @Valorum Scroll down the page you linked to and you'll see *Falcon* in italics. Also, the canon books use italics for ship names (e.g. *Carrion Spike* in the novel *Tarkin*).

Comment: another issue w/ the question: technically Han doesn't identify the Star Destroyers as anything other than "Imperial cruisers". When he says "big Corellian ships" he is sitting in the cantina - thus we don't necessarily know what ships he is referring to. He didn't know the Star Destroyers that case them in orbit were even there initially. This question is bordering on applying real-world examples / explainations

Comment: @Buzz "... the name seems to indicate that they are the spacegoing equivalents of naval destroyers. " Though I see your logic, this may not have been the writer's (Lucas') intent. It is not uncommon for movies to mix up terms.

Answer (score 11):

Han (and other characters) may have called the Star Destroyers "cruisers" since the [*Venator*-class Star Destroyer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Venator-class_Star_Destroyer) used by the Republic during the Clone Wars (and a predecessor design to the Imperial Star Destroyer) was sometimes called the ["Republic Attack Cruiser"](https://www.starwars.com/databank/republic-attack-cruiser).

The use of the name ["cruiser"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cruiser) in *Star Wars* refers to ships of a wide range of sizes, varying from a small ["consular" cruiser](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Consular-class_space_cruiser) like [the one used at the beginning of Episode I](https://www.starwars.com/databank/republic-cruiser) (which could only carry dozens of passengers at most) to capital ships like the [Mon Calamari cruisers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/MC80_star_cruiser). **In *Star Wars*, cruisers are not strictly larger than destroyers.**

Answer (score 0):

Ship's burrow from Naval terminology. IN the pre-disney expanded Universe, the republic Navy adopted a length/tonnage classification system for naval hierarchy for it's warships.

- Corvette: 100-200 meters (Example: CR90, Raider)
- Frigate (Light cruiser): 200-400 meters (EF76 Nebulon)
- Cruiser: 400-600 meters
- Heavy Cruiser: 600-1000 meters
- Star Destroyer: 1000-2000 meters (with some coming under)
- Battlecruiser: 2000-5000 meters (variances depending on the Navy)
- Dreadnought: Larger than 5000 meters